# How to create runtime variable for reading csv file header using Pandas

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file .It logs some data depending upon the test condition.
The header file of this csv file is like below

```
  UTC Time(s)   SVID-1 Constel-1 Status-1   Zij-1 SVID-2 Constel-2 Status-2
   10102          1        G       P         0     2        G        P

   Zij-2          SVID-3    Constel-3   Status-3    Zij-3   .......

   0.3         3             G                A      --
  .....
```

Apart from UTC Time column, other columns may increase or decrease depending 
upon test condition or number of satellites I use.

If any extra satellite introduces or reduces then corresponding Svid,Constel, Status,Zij will be present or will not be there.

I am interested to know whether is it possible to create runtime variable for each column without looking into csv file header.